# Prove: $f\colon \mathbb{C}\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$, $f(z)=az$ ($a\neq 0$ in $\mathbb{C}$) a homomorphism.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Find its kernel. Is $f$ an isomorphism?

I feel that this question is incomplete as the operation on complex numbers is not given . Is this question solvable . 
When I tried to prove it is a homomorphism I got stuck in checking.

$f(x) = ax$ and $f(z)=az$
Which operation do I use to prove $f(x).f(y) =f(x.y)$ ?

Comment: Is $f(z)=at$? I don't think so

Comment: $f(z) = az$ is not necessarily a homomorphism of rings, precicely because $f(xy) =f(x)f(y)$ does not hold in general (only if $a = 0$ or $a = 1$ does this work). It is, however, a homomorphism of _groups_ for any $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question as you have written it is unclear.  However, here's what I think the question is meant to be:

> Prove that the mapping $f:\Bbb C \to \Bbb C$ defined by $f(z) = az$ where $a$ is a non-zero complex number is a homomorphism on the group $(\Bbb C,+)$.

What you have to prove, then, is that for any $a$, we have 
$$
f(x + y) = f(x) + f(y)
$$

Comment: Then my ker f ={0} and it is isomorphic isn't it

Comment: You mean $\ker f = \{0\}$ and $f$ **is an isomorphism**.  And yes, that's true.